# Disabling scrollbar of Winform control inside WPF control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, winforms-interop

I have a WindowsFormsHost, with a Winform control in it, inside a WPF Tab item.

I've set the scrollbar to 'Hidden' on the Tab Control, the Tab Item itself, the WindowsFormsHost AND the Winform control inside the Host.

The scrollbars are still there, so at this point I'm not sure where they're coming from. I've also disabled the scrollbar on the entire window itself.

I have `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"` set on all the aforementioned controls.

`ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"`
also has no effect.

Comment: Have you also set the `VerticalScrollBarVisibility` property? `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` affects the horizontal scroll bar: the one along the bottom of a window when something is too wide.

Comment: It was just an example. All scrollbars are visible irrespective of which ones I set to 'Hidden'

Comment: Hmm. What exactly are you setting it to? Are you literally settings its value to a string like in your example? You need to use the `ScrollBarVisibility` enumeration to specify a value, like so: `myScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Hidden;`. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollbarvisibility(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Sorry, need to clarify: the enum is necessary only if you are setting it in code. XAML should indeed work with the regular strings, as shown on the page I linked. If you're having trouble with the XAML, you may want to try setting it programmatically instead just to see what happens.

Comment: Ya I mean it compiles without problems, so the things are being set fine. Yes I'm setting them in the XAML, though I tried disabling the scrollbars programatically as well, which had no effect.

I've tried setting it programmatically the way you mentioned, also     

        this.VerticalScroll.Enabled = false;
            this.VerticalScroll.Visible = false;

I've tried all the available ways of disabling scrollbars on every control that is involved in that view, they're still there.

Comment: Do you know if the scrollbars are a part of the WPF visual tree or coming from within your winforms control? (You can use the app Snoop if you aren't sure to visually inspect your WPF App's visual tree)

Comment: @rmoore: this is what I am unsure of, so I opted for setting the Scrollbars to 'Hidden' on ALL the controls involved, because I truthfully cannot figure out where they're coming from.

Comment: I found a smaller Winform control that was used as part of the larger one, that had an AutoScroll = true; in a custom Init() function. Setting that to false fixed the scrollbars.